# syntaxerror unexpected token # in json at position 0 at object.parse (native)

Tags: javascript, json, node.js

I am testing a server.js file through curl from cmd for post request where I am getting the above error. I saw many related question and answers but nothing solves my problem.
Please provide me the solution.

This is my server.js

```
var app = require('express')();
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');

app.use(bodyParser.json()); // for parsing application/json

app.post('/data', function (req, res) {
console.log(req.body);
res.end();  
});

app.listen(3000);
```

and This is curl code from cmd,

```
C:\Users\user\Downloads\Compressed\curl.exe -d '{"key1":"value1", "key2":"value2"}' -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X POST http://localhost:3000/data
```

This is the error I am getting,

[error image. click here to see it.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wloa8.png)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are using following body

```
'{\"key1\":\"value1\", \"key2\":\"value2\"}'
```

Use following instead

```
"{\"key1\":\"value1\", \"key2\":\"value2\"}"
```

Comment: sorry, i have uploaded wrong picture. I was doing the same from first (without escaping). check the image once again.

Comment: Try to use "{\"key1\":\"value1\", \"key2\":\"value2\"}"

Comment: That wasn't worked. i have uploaded the wrong image which was tried by me. That too, didn't work.

Comment: I have executed following commend `curl.exe -d "{\"key1\":\"value1\", \"key2\":\"value2\"}" -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X POST http://localhost:3000/data` and it is working fine. Can you copy this and paste it and then try?

Comment: Please note I have replace single quotes `'` with double quotes `"`